# How to use CHtml::link(); inside "<li></li>" in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, yii-components, yii-chtml

I need to use `CHtml::link()` inside `" "`.

Here is my existing code:

```
    $html .="<li>\n <a href='books".$menu['items'][$itemId]['link']."'>
                     ".$menu['items'][$itemId]['label']."
                    </a> \n";

    $html .= buildMenutree($itemId, $menu);

    $html .= "</li> \n";
```

I hope I can find a nice solution.

Comment: Ok. Could you add an example of the expected url and the actual url your code produces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `CHtml` function in your string just as any other PHP function:

```
$html .="<li>\n " . CHtml::link($menu['items'][$itemId]['label'], $menu['items'][$itemId]['link']);
```

See [normalizeUrl](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#normalizeUrl-detail) for the url's you can use.